# Reuse my useFetch hook to perform POST requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have made a `useFetch` hook to perform data fetching when components initially load, and it works exactly as I'd like.

The problem I have now is that I want to perform a POST request of form data as well.

How could it be done given I'm fetching on render of the component, and not as a result of a particular action?

```
const useFetch = (url: string, config: any = {}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [refreshIncrement, setRefreshIncrement] = useState(0);
  const refresh = () => setRefreshIncrement((prev) => prev + 1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        await fetch(url, config)
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(res.json()));
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
              setData(data);
              setIsLoading(false);
          });
      } catch (e: any) {
        setError(true);
        setData(e.message);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url, refreshIncrement]);

  return { data, isLoading, error, refresh };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Please explain to me why the provided answer doesn't satisfy you? I'd would be happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `react-query`, but if for any reason you don't want to, the changes would be as follows:

Consider adding an `options` parameter, along with an `fetchOnInit` property, just like the 'react-query' package, to prevent the API call when the component mounts. Additionally, it may be helpful to move the `fetchData` function out of the `useEffect` and include it in the return of your `useFetch` custom hook.

**Improved Custom Hook**

```js
const useFetch = (
  url: string,
  config: any = {},
  options: { fetchOnInit: boolean } = { fetchOnInit: true }
) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const [refreshIncrement, setRefreshIncrement] = useState(0);
  const refresh = () => setRefreshIncrement((prev) => prev + 1);

  const mutate = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await fetch(url, config)
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) throw new Error(JSON.stringify(res.json()));
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    } catch (e: any) {
      setError(true);
      setData(e.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    options.fetchOnInit && mutate();
  }, [url, options.fetchOnInit, refreshIncrement]);

  return { data, isLoading, error, refresh, mutate };
};
```

**Usage**

```js
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = (props) => {
  const { mutate } = useFetch(
    "http://sample.com/api",
    {},
    { fetchOnInit: false }
  );

  const handleClick = async () => {
    await mutate();
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}></button>;
};
```